# Login loop on ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: login

i have tried a number of suggestions to get past this with no joy i am new to ubuntu and would appreciate some assistance
i do not have a Xauthority file
have run apt upgrade/install
sudo dpkg --configure

Answer (score 0):

follow my steps and tell me what happens
1 reboot your pc (if already on) or start your pc (if it was off)
2 wait tell login screen comes after that press ctrl+alt+F2 (fkey don't matter use any of then not f7)
3 login with your username and pass
4 are you able to run commands like ls pwd cd if you can then ok if you cant then your problem is diffrent
if your are able to run those command try to run this command
gnome-session
tell me output